# Use inheritance with stdvector based flocking

Tags: c++, subclass, stdvector, openframeworks, flock

At the moment I'm working at an assignment for which I have to make a flocking system with different subclasses that behave different. I'm working with OpenFrameworks and C++.
I'm pretty new to Open Frameworks and C++.

As a basis I us this code:
https://sites.google.com/site/ofauckland/examples/ofxflocking-example

The thing however is, that the structure of this code is different then I'm used to; making new class objects with 'new ...'

My question is, how can I use two flocking classes? To get started, first only with a different color for instance.

One of the subclasses I've added until now is this:

```
class Team1 : public Boid {
public:

   Team1(): Boid() {};
   Team1(int x, int y): Boid(x,y) {};



   void draw()
    {

    }
};
```

I used a virtual void draw for the void draw of the superclass Boid and used boids.push_back(*new Team1()); in setup and and mousedrag. This gives the following errors:

- expected type-specifier before `Team1`
- expected `)` before `Team1`
- no matching function for call to `std::vector<Boid, std::allocator<Boid> >::push_back(int&)`

WHOLE CODE: (all the code is in one testapp.cpp file to exclude linking problems)

```
//number of boids
const int BoidAmount = 25;
```

Superclass Boid:

```
class Boid {
public:
Boid();
Boid(int x, int y);

void update(vector<Boid> &boids);
virtual void draw() {};

void seek(ofVec2f target);
void avoid(ofVec2f target);
void arrive(ofVec2f target);

void flock(vector<Boid> &boids);

ofVec2f steer(ofVec2f target, bool slowdown);   

ofVec2f separate(vector<Boid> &boids);
ofVec2f align(vector<Boid> &boids);
ofVec2f cohesion(vector<Boid> &boids);

ofVec2f location,direction

,acceleration;

float r;
float attraction;
float maxspeed;
};
```

Constructors:

```
 //---Constructors(overload)-----------------------------------------
Boid::Boid() {
location.set(ofRandomWidth(),ofRandomHeight());
direction.set(0,0);
acceleration.set(0,0);
r = 3.0;
maxspeed = 4;
attraction = 0.05; 
}

Boid::Boid(int x, int y) {
location.set(x,y); //initial location
direction.set(0,0); //initial direction
acceleration.set(0,0); //initial acceleration   
r = 3.0;
maxspeed = 4; // initial max speed
attraction = 0.1; // initial max force
}
```

Subclasses:

```
class Team1 : public Boid {
public:

Team1(): Boid() {};
Team1(int x, int y): Boid(x,y) {};



void draw()
{
    // Draw a triangle rotated in the direction of direction
    float angle = (float)atan2(-direction.y, direction.x);
    float theta =  -1.0*angle;
    float heading2D = ofRadToDeg(theta)+90;

    ofPushStyle();
    ofFill();


    ofPushMatrix();
    ofTranslate(location.x, location.y);

    ofRotateZ(heading2D);
    ofSetColor(255,255,255,80);

    ofEllipse(0, -r*2, 7, 12);
    ofBeginShape();
    ofVertex(0, -r*2);
    ofVertex(-r, r*2);
    ofVertex(r, r*2);
    ofEndShape(true);   
    ofPopMatrix();
    ofPopStyle();
}
};

class Team2 : public Boid {
public:

Team2(): Boid() {};
Team2(int x, int y): Boid(x,y) {};


void draw()
{


}

};

Methods:

// Method to update location
void Boid::update(vector<Boid> &boids) {

flock(boids);

direction += acceleration;   // Update direction
direction.x = ofClamp(direction.x, -maxspeed, maxspeed);  // Limit speed
direction.y = ofClamp(direction.y, -maxspeed, maxspeed);  // Limit speed
location += direction;
acceleration = 0;  // Reset accelertion to 0 each cycle

if (location.x < -r) location.x = ofGetWidth()+r;
if (location.y < -r) location.y = ofGetHeight()+r;

if (location.x > ofGetWidth()+r) location.x = -r;
if (location.y > ofGetHeight()+r) location.y = -r;
}

//SEEK
void Boid::seek(ofVec2f target) {
acceleration += steer(target, false);
}



// A method that calculates a steering vector towards a target
// Takes a second argument, if true, it slows down as it approaches the target
ofVec2f Boid::steer(ofVec2f target, bool slowdown) {
   ofVec2f steer;  // The steering vector
   ofVec2f desired = target - location;  // A vector pointing from the location to the target

float d = ofDist(target.x, target.y, location.x, location.y); // Distance from the target is the magnitude of the vector


// If the distance is greater than 0, calc steering (otherwise return zero vector)
if (d > 0) {

    desired /= d; // Normalize desired

    // Two options for desired vector magnitude (1 -- based on distance, 2 -- maxspeed)
    if ((slowdown) && (d < 100.0f)) {
        desired *= maxspeed * (d/100.0f); // This damping is somewhat arbitrary
    } else {
        desired *= maxspeed;
    }
    // Steering = Desired minus direction
    steer = desired - direction;
    steer.x = ofClamp(steer.x, -attraction, attraction); // Limit to maximum steering force
    steer.y = ofClamp(steer.y, -attraction, attraction); 

}
return steer;
}



//----------FLOCKING-BEHAVIOUR-------------------------------------------

void Boid::flock(vector<Boid> &boids) {
ofVec2f Seperation = separate(boids);
ofVec2f Alignment = align(boids);
ofVec2f Cohesion = cohesion(boids);

// Arbitrarily weight these forces
Seperation *= 1.5;
Alignment *= 1.0;
Cohesion *= 1.0;

acceleration += Seperation + Alignment + Cohesion;
}

//--SEPERATION--
// Method checks for nearby boids and steers away
ofVec2f Boid::separate(vector<Boid> &boids) {
float desiredseparation = 30.0;
ofVec2f steer;
int count = 0;

// For every boid in the system, check if it's too close
for (int i = 0 ; i < boids.size(); i++) {
    Boid &other = boids[i];

    float d = ofDist(location.x, location.y, other.location.x, other.location.y);

    // If the distance is greater than 0 and less than an arbitrary amount (0 when you are yourself)
    if ((d > 0) && (d < desiredseparation)) {
        // Calculate vector pointing away from neighbor
        ofVec2f diff = location - other.location;
        diff /= d;          // normalize
        diff /= d;        // Weight by distance
        steer += diff;
        count++;            // Keep track of how many
    }
}
// Average -- divide by how many
if (count > 0) {
    steer /= (float)count;
}


// As long as the vector is greater than 0
//float mag = sqrt(steer.x*steer.x + steer.y*steer.y);

float mag = sqrt(steer.x*steer.x + steer.y*steer.y);
if (mag > 0) {
    // Steering = Desired - direction
    steer /= mag;
    steer *= maxspeed;
    steer -= direction;
    steer.x = ofClamp(steer.x, -attraction, attraction);
    steer.y = ofClamp(steer.y, -attraction, attraction);
}
return steer;
}

//--ALIGNMENT--
// For every nearby boid in the system, calculate the average direction
ofVec2f Boid::align(vector<Boid> &boids) {
float neighbordist = 60.0;
ofVec2f steer;
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < boids.size(); i++) {
    Boid &other = boids[i];

    float d = ofDist(location.x, location.y, other.location.x, other.location.y);
    if ((d > 0) && (d < neighbordist)) {
        steer += (other.direction);
        count++;
    }
}
if (count > 0) {
    steer /= (float)count;
}

// As long as the vector is greater than 0
float mag = sqrt(steer.x*steer.x + steer.y*steer.y);
if (mag > 0) {
    // Implement Reynolds: Steering = Desired - direction
    steer /= mag;
    steer *= maxspeed;
    steer -= direction;
    steer.x = ofClamp(steer.x, -attraction, attraction);
    steer.y = ofClamp(steer.y, -attraction, attraction);
}
return steer;
}

//--COHESION--
// For the average location (i.e. center) of all nearby boids, calculate steering vector towards     that location
ofVec2f Boid::cohesion(vector<Boid> &boids) {
float neighbordist = 50.0;
ofVec2f sum;   // Start with empty vector to accumulate all locations
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < boids.size(); i++) {
    Boid &other = boids[i];
    float d = ofDist(location.x, location.y, other.location.x, other.location.y);
    if ((d > 0) && (d < neighbordist)) {
        sum += other.location; // Add location
        count++;
    }
}
if (count > 0) {
    sum /= (float)count;
    return steer(sum, false);  // Steer towards the location
}
return sum;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
bool isMouseMoving() {
static ofPoint pmouse;
ofPoint mouse(ofGetMouseX(),ofGetMouseY());
bool mouseIsMoving = (mouse!=pmouse);
pmouse = mouse;
return mouseIsMoving;
}
```

vector initialize:

```
std::vector<Boid*> boids;
```

-

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::setup() {
ofSetBackgroundAuto(false);
ofBackground(0,0,0);
ofSetFrameRate(60);
ofEnableAlphaBlending();
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) 
{
    boids.push_back(new Team1());
    //boids.push_back(Boid());
}
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::update() {


    for(int i=0; i<boids.size(); i++) {            
        boids[i]->seek(ofPoint(mouseX,mouseY));
    }



    for(int i=0; i<boids.size(); i++) {
        boids[i]->update(boids);
    }

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::draw() {

ofSetColor(0,0,0,20);
ofRect(0,0,ofGetWidth(),ofGetHeight());

for(int i=0; i<boids.size(); i++) 
{
    boids[i]->draw();
}
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::mouseDragged(int x, int y, int button) {


boids.push_back(new Team1(x,y));
    ////boids.push_back(Boid());
    //boids.push_back(Boid(x,y));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error, it seems like you have a `std::vector<Boid>`. You need to hold `Boids` polymorphically, so your vector should hold (preferably smart) pointers to `Boid`:

```
std::vector<Boid*> boids;
```

or

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Boid>> boids;
```

which you then can fill like this:

```
boids.push_back(new Team1());
```

or

```
boids.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Boid>(new Team1()));
```

respectively.

Note that [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) requires C++11 support. More on [smart pointers here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer).

Comment: Thanks, this made me got rid of the 'no matching function' error but regrettably gave me another one.In this part: for(int i=0; i<boids.size(); i++) { boids[i]->update(boids); } It gives the error 'no matching function for call to 'Boid::update(std::vector<Boid*, std::allocator<Boid*> >&)'' The void update in my Boid superclass looks like this: void update(vector<Boid> &boids); The whole code is in my question now.

Comment: @user1803370 well, you still have some mismatch between `vector<Boid>` and `vector<Boid*>`.

Comment: Thank you! that was just stupid. That was what I initially adapted but it gave me an error so I thought it was the wrong way. No it turns out that the reference had to be edited also of course. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be certain without seeing more code, but I guess the code calling `boids.push_back(*new Team1());` cannot see the definition of `Team1`. You need to `#include` a header file defining `Team1` in every .cpp file where you want to use it.

Also, to be able to use polymorphism (virtual functions), you must store *pointers* in your vector, not the actual objects. So you must type your vector as `std::vector<Boid*>`. Or preferably use a smart pointer, such as `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Boid> >`.

Comment: To make sure linking isn't causing any problems now, I've put all code in testapp.cpp.

This seems to help a lot. I got stuck with one error still though.
In this part:
  for(int i=0; i<boids.size(); i++) {
   boids[i]->update(boids);
  }

It gives the error 'no matching function for call to 'Boid::update(std::vector<Boid*, std::allocator<Boid*> >&)''

The void update in my Boid superclass looks like this:
 void update(vector<Boid> &boids);

I will put the whole code in my question.